# How to use standalone class to produce bitmap files with different names?

Tags: standalone, shell-escape

I have a few TikZ pictures in my document using the `standalone` class (with `-shell-escape`, and I want the resulting bitmaps to have more human-friendly names than `file-0.png`, `file-1.png` etc.  I thought this would help:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\begin{document}

% spam
\standaloneconfig{convert={outname=spam}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {spam};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Eggs
\standaloneconfig{convert={outname=eggs}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {eggs};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it didn't.  Neither did using `outfile`, nor `\def\outfile{spam.png}` before the first picture.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following process works for me on Windows.  First, the following code will create your `PNG` files and a file called `tempRename.bat` that contains `DOS` commands for renaming those `PNG` files to your desired names (the `-shell-escape` option is necessary for the `\write18` function).

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{num}
\write18{echo REM > tempRename.bat}

% spam
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {spam};
\end{tikzpicture}
\immediate\write18{echo ren \jobname-\thenum.png spam.png >> tempRename.bat}
\stepcounter{num}

% Eggs
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {eggs};
\end{tikzpicture}
\immediate\write18{echo ren \jobname-\thenum.png eggs.png >> tempRename.bat}
\stepcounter{num}

\end{document}
```

Second, run the `tempRename.bat` file to do the renaming.  If you put the LaTeX command and tempRename command in a batch file, then you can do the picture creation and renaming just by running the one batch file.

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
tempRename
pause
```

**EDIT:**  Latex code is updated so that the image filename numbers are no longer hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite clever! However, not fully satisfactory: the numbers are hardcoded, so moving pictures around is a no-no. I guess this would be easy to fix by looking at `standalone`'s source code and finding the relevant counter, so if nothing else comes up, I might end up doing the equivalent thing in bash.

Comment: @mbork:  Good catch, I didn't think about needing to move the pictures around.  I have updated the code in my answer.  There is a new counter defined so that the numbers are now dynamic.